# How do I install a minimal Ubuntu - no desktop needed?

Tags: system-installation

I keep having to re-install Ubuntu after trying advice.  This is very frustrating.  All I want is to boot to a Linux command prompt.  Please help!

Comment: For emulation, have a look at the Ubuntu cloud images: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Ubuntu minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) to install a base system.

It will contain the Linux kernel, basic Linux tools and the Debian APT system to install any other packages you might need manually.

The downloaded ISO for 11.10 is 23MB and after install (on my system) occupied around 600MB (rest of packages to install the system are downloaded via a network connection).

You will be able to choose the packages you want during the installation or after your reboot your system you can install anything individually with `apt-get` or by choosing packages by typing `sudo tasksel`.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.  I have plenty of disk space though.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You're probably best off with the Ubuntu Server install. By default it installs only the basic system, resulting in a fast machine with a small memory and disk footprint. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download

Comment: That may be the best solution.  I need FTP server.  Not concerned about disk space.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to do all your command line stuff from a LiveCD such as the one you used to install Ubuntu? If you have access to Windows and a flash drive you can always try UNetBootin to make a LiveUSB.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: No as I will not be actually using the command line. I am trying to run a dedicated application that is run from the command line.  That's all.  I plan to have a bash.profile that will execute this application.  That is all I want to do.  No cloud, no music, no videos, no email, no internet, no commands on the command line, nothing except to launch the application from a Linux environment.  After that it becomes an automated system.   A bit weird I know.