# Install Ubuntu without a DE , e.g KDE / Unity / XFCE , possible?

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a minimal Ubuntu install - no desktop needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112496/how-to-get-a-minimal-ubuntu-install-no-desktop-needed)

Can I install a `clean` ubuntu system , with no pre-installed Desktop Environment , like Unity or XFCE

Thanks